# Can the Filter function's range argument be a reference to a cell whose value is a range reference?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have this formula (simplified because it is long):

```
=FILTER(range,C3=TRUE,range<>"")
```

In place of `range` can I refer to the cell `AC2` that would contain the `range` name?

I have two ranges, `Range1` & `Range2`. I want execute different Filters depending which range a user selects from the dropdown.

[image]

Something like this...

```
=IFS(AC2="Range1", filter_function1, 
     AC2="Range2", filter_function2)`
```

This is because I want the filtering range to change with the users' selection.
I tried just referring to that cell K2, but got an error.

Then, I put an IF condition instead of range in the filter criteria, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `INDIRECT` function to turn a string into a reference like so,

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT("range1"), INDIRECT("range1") <> "")
```

But this function does have a flaw that you have to change the values in two different places, and as the filter grows, it becomes even more cumbersome to update. We can utilize the new function, `LET`.

```
=LET(name,INDIRECT("range1"), FILTER(name,name <> ""))
```

---[Learn more about LET here.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535)---

you can also use the `LAMBDA` function if you want. But it is older and a bit clunky looking.

```
=LAMBDA(name,FILTER(name, name <> ""))((INDIRECT("range1")))
```